# Adaptar User Control en un panel en Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, usercontrol

Estoy siguiendo un curso de Udemy, pero me salto una duda y querida ver si me pueden ayudar con un problema, es con respecto a los user control, después crear y editar mi user control, cuando hago a mostrarlo en un panel este me sale super expandido y no me muestra todos los datos que debería, esto debido a lo grande que aparece.

El Código que empleo en el boton para mostrar el user control es el siguiente:

```
Personal2 formulariomostrar = new Personal2();    
panelPadre.Controls.Clear();
formulariomostrar.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 
panelPadre.Controls.Add(formulariomostrar);
```

Este es el User Control que deseo mostrar
[image: Este es el User Control que deseo mostrar]

Pero me sale de esta manera, incluso se puede ver como los label que tengo alineados en el user control se desalinean cuando lo muestro en el panel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! alguna forma de que podamos replicar tu problema?? probaste tenerlo cargado siempre, y solo ponerlo visible, invisible? a ver si cuando lo pones se ve bien?

Comment: La propiedad `formulariomostrar.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;` es la que está haciendo que tu `user control` llene todo el espacio del contenedor, cambia el valor asignado a la `Dock` probando varias opciones, para que puedas elegir, la más conveniente según tus necesidades.